# Using R to import specific records from a PDB file

Tags: r, pdb

I'm using R and I'm trying to import specific records from a PDB file (e.g. `HETNAM`, `HETSYN`). Unfortunately, it seems the `read.pdb` function of either `biomaRt` or `Rpdb` aren't capable of it.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, could you show what have you tried? As far as I know it is not so difficult to parse the files, but that depends on the format of the file you downloaded.

Comment: Hi, nothing special, I just used the read.pdb function to read in the PDB files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your file is in PDB format as the one shown [here](https://files.rcsb.org/view/6C4A.pdb) in .pdb format then you can simply extract your desired fields using [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) which is a programming language used to parse and transform text. As for this [structure](https://files.rcsb.org/view/6C4A.pdb) i.e 6C4A in .pdb format HETNAM and HETSYN can be extracted using sed as follows:

```
sed  -n -e '/HETNAM/ p' -e '/HETSYN/ p'  6C4A.pdb

HETNAM     EJA S-[(1Z)-2-CARBOXY-N-HYDROXYETHANIMIDOYL]-L-CYSTEINE              
HETNAM     PYR PYRUVIC ACID                                                     
HETNAM      MG MAGNESIUM ION                                                    
HETNAM     3NP 3-NITROPROPANOIC ACID                                            
HETNAM     PEG DI(HYDROXYETHYL)ETHER                                            
HETNAM     EPE 4-(2-HYDROXYETHYL)-1-PIPERAZINE ETHANESULFONIC ACID              
HETSYN     EPE HEPES
```

Comment: Thanks, seems pretty straightforward. How do I use sed? Is it a way to apply it on R ?

Comment: It is straight forward. Write this command on Linux command line/terminal with your input file present in current working directory.

Comment: Secondly for using sed in R you should check [this](https://jpwendler.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/using-a-linux-sed-command-to-retrieve-specific-rows-from-a-file-from-r/amp/)